# How to detect position in the last 6 month in panda

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column( position and date), and I want to know the positions in the last 6 months.

I think I should use grouby and: `df["Data"].dt.month`

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Post a sample of the data please

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example